# Get value from column A where column B have exact number of values while grouped by column A

Tags: mysql

I have a table with values (ids) in MySQL:

| columnA | columnB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | v1 |
| 1 | v2 |
| 2 | v1 |
| 2 | v2 |
| 2 | v3 |

I'm trying to select a single value of columnA by querying values in columnB, while grouped by columnA and where columnB should match exact values passed to query.

E.g. if you pass v1 and v2 it should only get id 1 from columnA

The closest I got is:

```
   SELECT cA, cB
   FROM table
   WHERE cA in (
       SELECT cA
       FROM table
       WHERE cB in (v1, v2)
       GROUP BY cA
   )
   GROUP BY cA, cB
   HAVING cB IN (v1, v2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by column A to concat values in column B, and then compare the input string

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT cA, GROUP_CONCAT(cB) AS cBG
  FROM t1
  WHERE cB IN ("v1", "v2")
  GROUP BY cA
) z
WHERE z.cBG = "v1,v2";
```

Output:

```
cA      cBG
---------------
 1      v1,v2
```

For input "v1,v2,v3"

Output:

```
 cA        cBG
----------------
 2      v1,v2,v3
```

[Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0f07c/20)

Comment: Thanks Samir, wouldn't this be better with a where clause? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0f07c/19/0

Comment: You are right, adding a where clause to subquery would optimize it. I thought I had used it but somehow missed. Updated my fiddle and query in the answer.